# How Do I Import the Redis Python Module?

Tags: python, django

I ran my project and received the following error:

```
File "/home/nguyentv/schoollink/web/views/apis.py", line 10, in <module>
    from util.redis.redis_client import Redis
ImportError: No module named util.redis.redis_client
```

How do I properly import this library?

Comment: Is this some existing code you are trying to run or are you writing this own your own?

Comment: This is the current code when I try to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

[The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory). PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path. The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more information.

Basically, the interpreter is going to perform a lookup in your current working directory, then it will search through the system defined library directories.

The issue you are facing could be that your code is looking for a module that does not exist, you are calling the script from an incorrect directory, or the `sys.path` is setup incorrectly.

I could help more if you showed how you instantiated the interpreter, `pwd` output, and `tree` output.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import Redis from a package named `util`. Unless this package is part of your application, it does not exist.

According to [python-redis' documentation](https://pypi.org/project/redis/), here is how to import it:

```
import redis
# then use redis.Redis(...)
```

or, equivalently:

```
from redis import Redis
# then use Redis(...)
```